# How many products have been uploaded per week?

Tags: mysql

I have a product table with `product_id` and `entry_date` field (which is varchar). I want to get result of how many products have been uploaded per week. Please tell me the SQL so that I can get the result of how many products have been uploaded per week.

I also have user_id field.I also need how many products have been uploaded per week per user.

Thanks very much for the above help.Now I also want user_name,created_by,entry_date(in date format),uploads.I have a table of user_registration where primary key is user_id.It has user_name field.I have understood that I have to join but which join should I do that I can't decide can you help me by explaining which join and why I use?

Comment: _Please tell me the SQL_ - here we would generally rather you have it an honest go, and then someone will help you with a more specific query. It's pretty mandatory to provide a `CREATE TABLE` statement so people can get an idea of what you're working with too `:)`

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(product_id) as uploads
from product 
group by week(cast(entry_date as date))
```

### edit

```
select user_id,
       count(product_id) as uploads, 
       week(cast(entry_date as date)) as week
from product 
group by user_id, week
```

See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70973/1)

Comment: I also need by each user.I also have user_id field in table.

Comment: update your question and add an example and I will have a look at it.

Comment: +1 for actually answering this question.